# Navigation Component when using Menu Buttons

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#8) for learning Navigation Components.
My basic set up to test Navigation UI of menu buttons of Toolbar is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/detail_dest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_details"
            android:title="@string/details"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="@string/settings"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


    <item
            android:id="@+id/camera_dest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:title="@string/camera"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Navigation graph is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
              android:name="com.example.navmenu.MainFragment"
              android:label="fragment_main" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <action android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_detail_dest"
                app:destination="@id/detail_dest"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
    </fragment>

    <!-- Detail Fragment -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/detail_dest"
              android:name="com.example.blankfragments.DetailFragment"
              android:label="fragment_detail" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"/>

    <!-- Settings Fragment -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
              android:name="com.example.blankfragments.SettingsFragment"
              android:label="fragment_settings" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/camera_dest"
              android:name="com.example.blankfragments.CameraFragment"
              android:label="fragment_camera" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_camera"/>
</navigation>
```

My first question is when i touch a fragment on screen, for instance SettingsFragment when it's already on screen it's re-created, can this be prevented, if so, is it possible only by modifying xml?

Second question is tutorial says that ids of items in menu.xml should be same with fragment ids.
`detail_dest` in menu should be `detail_dest` in nav_graph either. However i want the transition to be done with Animation as it happens when you use actions. When i change use menu item with id it only goes once to Detail Fragment and without animation, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is when i touch a fragment on screen, for instance
>   SettingsFragment when it's already on screen it's re-created, can this
>   be prevented, if so, is it possible only by modifying xml?

This can be prevented. But you can't do this from xml. To do this, you have to write kotlin code.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val currentDestID = navController.currentDestination?.id

        return if(item.itemId == currentDestID){
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }else{
            ((item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController))
                    || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        }


}
```

Here, by `item.itemId == currentDestID` this condition I have checked whether clicked menu id is the same as the current page id. If the same id is clicked then I have just called super.

**This solution will work only for Options menu**

> When i change use menu item with id it only goes once to Detail
>   Fragment and without animation, how can i fix this?

As of version `2.2.0-alpha02` there is no way to add animation when you are using `NavigationUI`. You can view the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F&autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#74). They have initialized the default animation.